# How can I add a Button on bottom of SliverAppBar and make it overlap on ExtentList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've try to put a Column(a Container inside) in SliverAppBar bottom property as a button, but it can't overlap the ExtentList ,just overflow the bottom margin.
I want to make it overlapped just like Spotify App do.

this is Spotify Sample:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdWtS.jpg

this is what I've tried:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcCVP.jpg

My code:

```dart
class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
            sliver: SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 300,
              title: Text(
                'Testing',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text(''),
                background: Image.asset(
                  'images/w.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              bottom: PreferredSize(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'test',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(109, 76, 65, 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    height: 54,
                    width: 100,
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(//extentlist)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show your try and result.

Comment: thx for comment, code and result added.

Comment: I can't get overflow error through this code.

Comment: what kind of error occured on you ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {
  static const double _appBarBottomBtnPosition =
      24.0; //change this value to position your button vertically

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Testing',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 300.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25),
              title: Text('Title'),
              background: Image.asset(
                'images/w.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0.0),
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(0, _appBarBottomBtnPosition),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  child: Text("Click Here"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _appBarBottomBtnPosition),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
              //extentlist
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! It's just what I need.Transform Widget's really useful that I don't know before, looks like I need to dive in Transform.

Comment: Two SliverAppBar !
Isn't it bad to have that two SliverAppBar ? I Think it's better to use SliverPersistentHeader 
https://developpaper.com/create-interesting-scrolling-effects-in-flutter-sliver-series/

Comment: one thing to note , sometimes the button is not responsive when clicked in my case...comment if you have same issue or solution

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided by @Crazy Lazy Cat works .. but if you are worried about using 2 SliverAppBar 's. you can substitute with the code below to replace the 2 SliverAppBar

```
 SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 500.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset(
                'images/w.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0.0),
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(0, _appBarBottomBtnPosition),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  child: Text("Click Here"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```