# Overlapping card effect in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

How can I create an overlapping card effect in a **SliverAppBar** as shown in the figure:

[image: Overlapping card]

I tried following [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f) article of Medium but the problem is it uses **Stack** with

```dart
Stack{
  ...
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
  ...
}
```

to implement this and in Stack, overflowing part of widgets don't take inputs thus making my **TabBar half Dead**.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: maybe try `OverflowBox` or `SizedOverflowBox`

Comment: No. I used SizedOverflowBox but it still doesn't take any input.

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403258/how-can-i-add-a-button-on-bottom-of-sliverappbar-and-make-it-overlap-on-extentli/59404244#59404244). It may help you

Answer (score 0):

**Full Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MenuList(),
    );
  }
}

class MenuList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuListState createState() => _MenuListState();
}


class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {
  static const double _appBarBottomBtnPosition =
  24.0; //change this value to position your button vertically

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Testing',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25),
              title: Text('Title'),
            ),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0.0),
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(0, _appBarBottomBtnPosition),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  child: Text("Click Here"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _appBarBottomBtnPosition),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 50,
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index){
                  Color color = Colors.red.withOpacity(1- (index%10)/10);
                  return Container(
                    color: color,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Color: $color"),
                  );
                }
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even after using ```PreferredSize``` and ```Transform.translate``` , the part lying outside is not responsive.