# How to make an icon rest on the edge of container flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I make an icon rest on the bottom of a container, just like in the picture. So that even when I scroll the page and the container moves. The icon moves with it in that particular position.
The icon in this page is the empty profile icon resting on the container with the exes image. I don't want my container to have an image though.

**Just color  image of the container and round icon.**

[image: image of the container and round icon]

**Image of the container and icon even when scrolled.**

[image: Image of the container and icon even when scrolled]

NOTE. I don't want the container to be the app bar. Just a container on its own under the app bar. I'm only showing this picture so u can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want it like this :
[image]

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.cyan[900],
            ),
            Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.grey[900],
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 150, // +50 below circle Container
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        'Happiness',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 32),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 300,
                        color: Colors.amber[900],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 300,
                        color: Colors.red[900],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: -100,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/cyanide.png',
                      )),
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

may be what you need is to use CustomScrollView and SilverAppBar with bottom:

here is the reference: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403258/how-can-i-add-a-button-on-bottom-of-sliverappbar-and-make-it-overlap-on-extentli)

plus transform